# ¿Cómo muestro los datos de mi base de datos SQLite en un Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

Recién empecé a programar en android studio así que es mi primera vez intentando hacer esto pero no puedo hacerlo. Esta es mi Base de Datos:

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos) {
        BaseDeDatos.execSQL("CREATE TABLE productos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nombreP text, cantidad integer, precio real)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Aqui es donde quiero mostrar los datos de la base de datos

```
public class PantallaPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView ListaProductos;
    Button Agregar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantalla_principal);

        ListaProductos = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Rv_Productos);
        Agregar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn_floatAdd);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(PantallaPrincipal.this, AgregarProductos.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

y una imagen de como se ve el activity:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, esta pregunta la has hecho esta mañana y se considera repetida, deberías eliminar esta y volver a la anterior, que te han hecho un comentario con un enlace para ayudarte con tu problema.

Comment: Como mencioné anteriormente, en tu pregunta anterior, hay muchas preguntas en el sitio que responden a esta inquietud. Y si lo que quieres es poblar un `RecyclerView` con datos `SQLite` debes tener en cuenta ciertas cosas. A)- Crear un adaptador para el `RecyclerView` B)- Crear las consultas para tus listas en SQLite C)- Poblar tu `RecyclerView` usando el `Adaptador` y `Arrays` que carguen las consultas de `SQLite`. Y como dije: en el sitio hay muchas de estas preguntas que puedes usar para guiarte y en google encontrarás tutoriales CRUD

Answer (score 0):

Deberás crear dos clases mas,como yo tengo entendido funciona así:

Adaptador.java

Acá serán donde tus entidades se relacionen con tu clase principal, te pongo mi ejemplo:

```
public class adapterList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterList.ViewHolder> {
private List<additemlist>mData;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;

public adapterList(List<additemlist> itemlist, Context context){
    this.mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context=context;
    this.mData=itemlist;
}
@Override
public adapterList.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_clientes,null);
    return new adapterList.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final adapterList.ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
    holder.bindData(mData.get(position));
}
public void setItem(List<additemlist> items){mData=items;}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView iconImage;
    TextView name, city, status;
    ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        //  iconImage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.iconlist);
        name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
        city=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdeuda);
        status=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
    }
    void bindData(final additemlist item){
        //iconImage.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(item.getColor()), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        name.setText(item.getXcodigo());
        city.setText(item.getXcliente());
        status.setText(item.getXsituacion());
    }
}
```

}

Entidades.java

En esta clase deberás poner el nombre de las columnas de la tabla que creaste en SQLite y ahora quieres llamarlo, yo pienso que funcionan como un almacenador, ahi te dejo otro ejemplo:

```
public class additemlist {
String xcodigo;
private String xcliente;
private String xtipo;

/*public additemlist(String xcodigo, String xcliente, String xtipo, String xsituacion) {
    this.xcodigo = xcodigo;
    this.xcliente = xcliente;
    this.xtipo = xtipo;
    this.xsituacion = xsituacion;
}*/

private String xsituacion;

public String getXcodigo() { return xcodigo; }

public void setXcodigo(String xcodigo) { this.xcodigo = xcodigo; }

public String getXcliente() { return xcliente; }

public void setXcliente(String xcliente) {this.xcliente = xcliente;}

public String getXtipo() {return xtipo;}

public void setXtipo(String xtipo) {this.xtipo = xtipo;}

public String getXsituacion() {return xsituacion;}

public void setXsituacion(String xsituacion) { this.xsituacion = xsituacion; }
```

}

Finalmente lo llamas en tu clase principal para que lo puedas visualizar en tu Recyclerview.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpLDIgjngyA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtWgbmEe_x4

Estos dos videos me ayudaron a mí para entender como se comunicaban. :D

Saludos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, de acuerdo al código que escribe el OP como se aplicaría el código que agregas en tu respuesta?, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.